# Apply Color Picker Selection to Div Font

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

1. How would I apply the selected color from the color-picker to the these divs: #header, #subHeader, #button ?
2. How can I hide the border of the div #button until the user types text into `<input id="text3" class="textInput">`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div1 = $('#header')[0];

    $('#text1').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div1.innerHTML = this.value;
    }); 

    var div2 = $('#subHeader')[0];

    $('#text2').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div2.innerHTML = this.value;
    });

    var div3 = $('#button')[0];

    $('#text3').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div3.innerHTML = this.value;
    });
});


$(".basic").spectrum();
$(".override").spectrum({
    color: "yellow"
});
$(".startEmpty").spectrum({
    allowEmpty: true
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#header {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#subHeader {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

#button {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/spectrum.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div> 
<div id="subHeader"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
</div>

<h2>Header</h2><input id="text1" class="textInput">
<h2>Subheader</h2><input id="text2" class="textInput">
<h2>Button</h2><input id="text3" class="textInput">
<h2>Color</h2>
<input type='text' class="basic" />
```

Comment: Is this question sufficiently formatted? I'm not sure exactly where to start with the color picker, so I couldn't really try anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will change your `#subHeader` color.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div1 = $('#header')[0];

    $('#text1').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div1.innerHTML = this.value;
    }); 

    var div2 = $('#subHeader')[0];

    $('#text2').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div2.innerHTML = this.value;
    });

    var div3 = $('#button')[0];

    $('#text3').bind('keyup change', function() {
        div3.innerHTML = this.value;
        if(this.value.length > 0) {
            $('#button').css('display', 'block')
        } else {
           $('#button').css('display', 'none')
        }
    });
});


$(".basic").spectrum({
   change: function(color) {
       console.log(color.toHexString());
       $('#subHeader').css('color',color.toHexString());
       var s = '2px solid ' + color.toHexString();
       $('#button').css('border', s);
}
});
$(".override").spectrum({
    color: "yellow"
});
$(".startEmpty").spectrum({
    allowEmpty: true
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#header {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#subHeader {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

#button {
  display:none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "helevtica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/226140/spectrum.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div> 
<div id="subHeader"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
</div>

<h2>Header</h2><input id="text1" class="textInput">
<h2>Subheader</h2><input id="text2" class="textInput">
<h2>Button</h2><input id="text3" class="textInput">
<h2>Color</h2>
<input type='text' class="basic" />
```

Comment: Almost! I added ` $('#header').css('color',color.toHexString()); ` and ` $('#button').css('color',color.toHexString()); ` but I still need to assign the color change to the border color on the button.

Comment: You need to add that in the change event, exactly like I did. If you consider is the correct answer please accept it, so other people with the same problem will know that is the good one.

Comment: does "adding that to the change event" look like this: $('#button').css('color','border'color.toHexString()); ? This does not work

Comment: Also, is there a way to hide the button border before anything is typed into the button text input?

Comment: Johny i updated the answer, so you have to change the css for button and add `display:none;` as default, and if the input value length for the button text field (#text3) is greater then 0 then change the display to block. Is it clear? did you need other information ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
$(".basic").spectrum({
    change: function(color) {
       console.log(color.toHexString());
       //add your code here
    }
});
```

Then you should add your code to change what you want based on the selected color. Let me know if this helped you, or if you have any other question.

Comment: By "add your code here" -- which code would I add there? Code you give an example?

Comment: added a new answer, with the change for subHeader, the other elements should be done in the same way. Is ok now ?

Comment: Johnny let me know if is ok now :) or if you need some additional help.